# Icons are not showing in Stack Overflow Chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

I have opened [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) from mobile device but I saw new version of mobile chat but when I select message I do not see icons like below :

[image: Icons not showing]

Device Specs : Huawei P8 Lite (Android 6) on Chrome for Android version 90

**Edit :** I tested it on Windows 10 Microsoft Edge Chromium 90 and one icon only showed and it take sometime to show. And sometimes not showed. Like Below :
[image: Windows 10 Microsoft Edge Chromium 90]

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. The icons are created in CSS with `background: url(../Img/mobile/toolbar/ico-reply.svg);`. Can you check if these resources are loaded or blocked?

Comment: I always thought it was by design. Although I could never understand when they show up and when they don't

Comment: @SebastianSimon Chrome for Android. I think that Chrome for Android does not have Devtools. :)

Comment: @Dharman Did you face same problem?

Comment: Yes, I do all the time

Comment: Can you reproduce it on desktop at all? There’s a “mobile” link on the chat page to switch to the mobile view. I’ve noticed that some of these icons have the `disabled` class which hides them. Do all icons (`<li>` elements) have the `disabled` class?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Some of them have disabled class not all;I updated my question; I think disabled class who create this problem :)

Comment: [Meta.SE report of the same bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357815/294691).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, although when I select a chat message the toolbar doesn't appear at all. Only when I scroll does it appear.

Comment: @Spectric I also noticed when I scroll. It showed icons.